# Implementing kernel timer in Ubuntu

Tags: 10.04, kernel, programming

Could you please give any basic example of a kernel timer (start_ktimer) implementation in Ubuntu?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be ubuntu-specific - perhaps you should ask on stackoverflow instead?

Comment: Or it could perhaps be asked at [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Kernel timers are described here: http://www.xml.com/ldd/chapter/book/ch06.html#t5

A quick example for a kernel module can be seen under the section "code for /proc/jitimer".